# How to go to very previous step while doing debugging in eclipse

Tags: java, debugging, web-applications

I tried to run an application but my application was stopped with error message (handled by exception) . I want to see the very previous step that caused the exception. 
Is there any way through debugging we can find out the previous step that caused the exception.

Comment: Well thats what breakpoints are for. Place one somewhere and step through it line by line.

Comment: :) that's when you know the flow .
For an unknown application what would be the approach

Comment: If you don't know the flow, catch the exception and print the stack trace. Then you'll get the flow.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is: no.

When an exception is thrown, we cannot "go back" in the IDE to the moment before the exception was thrown. The best way to analyze what has occured is to look at the stacktrace (which comes with the exception) to see where the exception occured. Then, place a breakpoint before the row which threw the exception, and look at the data involved. If something is awry, you will have to try to find the origin of the error.

One neat tick though is that you can "go back" to the previous stack frame, in most debuggers. This will take you back to the point just before entering the current method context (i.e. back to before the method you were in was called). In Eclipse, it looks like this:

[image]

It's a handy way to "go back" to the beginning of a method, in case you want to step through it again.

Answer (score 0):

You say "handled by exception", but you don't say whether it was handled by your try-catch block or by the unhandled exception handler common in many java environments (or perhaps it's the JVM, not sure).

You also don't say what your development environment is. The debuggers in both eclipse and netbeans (at least) allow you to stop on the line that is going to (or has) generated an unhandled exception. It is an option associated with the debugger.

There is also the stacktrace; this is a bunch of lines showing you the call stack at the point of the exception. This includes the method name, containing java file, and line number for each call up to the top of the stack. Normally an unhandled exception dumps this to the console and/or log file.

Hope that helps.